# Tangent vector of $\frac{1}{f}$

Tags: differential-geometry

On the smooth manifold $M$, suppose $v$ is a tangent vector to $x$. How can one show that for a differentiable function $f$ on $M$, non zero in a neighborhood of $x$, $v(\frac{1}{f})$= $- \frac{v(f)}{f(x)²}$

I just began studying tangent vector on smooth manifold and besides using Leibniz  rule and linearity of $v$ I have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply v on $1 = \frac{f}{f} = f \frac{1}{f}$ and use the Leibniz rule.